# UIActivityViewController presenting issue iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller

since iOS 8 I am having problems with displaying an `UIActivityViewController` on an iPad with iOS 8. This issue only appears on an iPad. This is my code:

```
    //Setting up activityItems...

    self.activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities];
    self.activityController.excludedActivityTypes = nil;

    self.activityController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = sellectedRect;

   [self presentViewController:self.activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This should be presented from an UIActionSheet. Now every time I press the button I get a log message:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIActivityViewController: 0x7fff15625e30>  on <MyViewController: 0x7fff13f20940> which is already presenting (null)
```

And I don't know what I should do with this message.
Does anyone know a fix?

Thanks, David.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your delegate for the UIActionSheet is like this:

```
- (void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
        clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    //present UIActivityViewController
    }
```

then... try to change it into this:

```
- (void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
 //present UIActivityViewController
}
```